# OCaml file I/O: why is add_channel returning empty content for /proc/<PID>/cmdline?

Tags: linux, file-io, ocaml

I'm trying to read the contents of `/proc/<PID>/cmdline`, but in one case I get an empty string, and in the other case I get the expected contents.

Why doesn't the following work with this file, but works for other files:

```
let read_file (filename : string) : string =
  let ic = open_in_bin filename in
  let len = in_channel_length ic in
  let buf = Buffer.create (in_channel_length ic) in
  Buffer.add_channel buf ic len;
  let content = Buffer.contents buf in
  close_in ic;
  content
```

However, the following works for all files, including `proc/<PID>/cmdline`:

```
let read_file (filename : string) : string =
  let ic = open_in filename in
  let buf = Buffer.create (in_channel_length ic) in
  let contents =
    try
      while true do
        let line = input_line ic in
        Buffer.add_string buf line;
        Buffer.add_char buf '\n';
      done; assert false
    with End_of_file ->
      Buffer.contents buf in
  String.trim contents
```

Comment: what does not work with the 1st implementation ?

Comment: On /proc/<PID>/stat, I get Sys_error with the terse message “Invalid Argument”. With /proc/<PID>/cmdline, I get an empty string back. Both kinds of files have content and I can read this content using the second method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version doesn't work because `/proc/<PID>/cmdline` (as well as any other file in the `procfs` virtual file system) is not a *regular* file, and `in_channel_length`

> (** Return the size (number of characters) of the regular file .. *)

You may notice, for example, that a `file` or `du` also think that the cmdline file is empty:

```
$ file /proc/1/cmdline 
/proc/1/cmdline: empty

$ du -h /proc/1/cmdline
0       /proc/1/cmdline
```

Your first function will not always work on other non-regular files, for example on pipes.

Comment: Oh, I found some discussion on this topic that pointed to this implementation (I think) that should do it correctly: http://caml.inria.fr/svn/ocaml/branches/constructors_with_record3/ocamldoc/odoc_misc.ml